# WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded

Tags: java, warnings, mime-types, apache-tika

I am using `Apache tika` to check file extensions.

But I got this warning when initializing the TikaConfig object.

```
org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
```

To initial config

```
public static TikaConfig getTikaConfig() {
        TikaConfig tikaConfig = null;
        try {
            return new TikaConfig();
        } catch (TikaException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tikaConfig;
    }
```

and use this object like following

```
public static final TikaConfig tikaConfig = getTikaConfig();
MediaType mediaType = tikaConfig.getDetector()
                                        .detect(TikaInputStream
                                                    .get(item.getInputStream()), new Metadata());
                MimeType mimeType = tikaConfig.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
                String extension =  mimeType.getExtension().split("\\.")[1];
```

My question is how to get rid of this warning.

PS: Gradle dependency for apache tika is

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '1.24.1'
runtime group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers' version: '1.24.1'
```

Comment: Do you want to process sqlite databases? And if so, what platform (Windows / Mac / Linux) are you using + hence need the native libraries for?

Comment: No, I don't want to process SQLite database BTW I am using windows

Comment: If you don't want to process SQLite databases, you can safely ignore the warning then! It is just telling you that it can't process them because Tika doesn't have the native libraries (which don't ship as they're huge and platform-specific)

Comment: There's an open defect in JIRA for this.